# Why null values coming if i make new dataset from existing dataset?

Tags: r

I have a dataset coll with 7593 observations and 22 variables. I am filtering the data and have to create another dataset coll2 from coll. I am trying following script:

```
 # identify field names
 cols<- c("MD_EARN_WNE_P10","PFTFAC","MEDIAN_HH_INC","PCTPELL",
     "UG25ABV","PCIP10","PCIP11", "PCIP14", "PCIP15",
     "PCIP26", "PCIP27", "PCIP29", "PCIP40", "PCIP41", 
     "PCIP47")

 # set select fields to numeric
 coll[cols] <- lapply(coll[cols], function(x) {as.numeric(levels(x))[x]})


 # create Fields
 coll$selective<-as.factor(ifelse(coll$CCUGPROF==14|coll$CCUGPROF==15,
                             1,0))

 coll$STEM<- (coll$PCIP10+coll$PCIP11+coll$PCIP14+coll$PCIP15+
           coll$PCIP26+coll$PCIP27+coll$PCIP29+coll$PCIP40+
           coll$PCIP41+coll$PCIP47)

# subset
coll<-subset(coll, PREDDEG == 3 & MAIN == 1 & 
           (CCUGPROF==5|CCUGPROF==6|CCUGPROF==7|
              CCUGPROF==8 |CCUGPROF==9 |CCUGPROF==10 |
              CCUGPROF==11 |CCUGPROF==12 |
              CCUGPROF==13 |CCUGPROF==14 |CCUGPROF==15),
         select=c(selective,
                  MD_EARN_WNE_P10,
                  MEDIAN_HH_INC,
                  STEM,
                  PCTPELL,
                  UG25ABV))

# remove specfied values
wordList <- c("PrivacySuppressed","NULL",NA)
coll2<-subset(coll, !MD_EARN_WNE_P10 %in% wordList 
          & !selective %in% wordList
          & !MEDIAN_HH_INC %in% wordList
          & !STEM %in% wordList
          & !PCTPELL %in% wordList
          & !UG25ABV %in% wordList)

# adjust units for percent fields
coll2$STEM<-coll2$STEM*100
coll2$PCTPELL<-coll2$PCTPELL*100
coll2$UG25ABV<-coll2$UG25ABV*100

 # adjust units for continuous variables
coll2$MD_EARN_WNE_P10<-coll2$MD_EARN_WNE_P10/1000
coll2$MEDIAN_HH_INC<-coll2$MEDIAN_HH_INC/1000
```

As i result, i get the coll2 with 0 observations of 6 variables? Where I am going wrong here? Why 0 observations are coming from Coll2?

I would really appreciate any sort of help

```
> dput(head(coll,10))
structure(list(selective = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
MD_EARN_WNE_P10 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), MEDIAN_HH_INC = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_
), STEM = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), PCTPELL = 
c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), UG25ABV = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_
 )), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), class 
 = 
 "data.frame")
```

Comment: We don't have `coll`, so while the code is somewhat helpful, having sample data would be significantly helpful as well. Can you post the output from `dput(head(coll,10))` into a code block, please?

Comment: A `NULL` return value from something is often caused by a typo in a column name.

Comment: I have put output of dput(head(coll,10)) now.

Comment: On the assumption that you want to *exclude` obs corresponding to entries in `wordList`, I suspect you want `(coll, !(MD_EARN_WNE_P10 %in% wordList)` and similar....

Comment: Thank you for providing some sample data, but ... (1) all columns except one are all `NA`; (2) most of the fields you reference in your post are not present. Please simplify your code to reflect the sample data (and explain/resolve the "all-`NA`" thing), or fix the sample data.